# Syncing two objects of different classes with each other

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

Suppose I am having three classes all independent of each other. Let's name them Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3. I am creating an object of Class 2 in Class 1 and Class 3 object in Class 2. Is there a way to figure out which object of class 2 is calling class 3 object. Actually I need to call the same object of class 2 from class 3 and do some operations on it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain the problem you are trying to solve with this approach. As written and without additional context it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can I pass object as a reference to another object of different class?

Comment: That question is also difficult to answer, because it doesn't make much sense. You can pass an object as a reference to a *method* of a different class (reference types always pass a reference).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the constructor of `Class3` accept a "parent" instance of `Class2` and then store that - this way they can keep track of eachother:

```
public class Class1 {
    private Class2 _class2;
    
    public Class1() {
        _class2 = new Class2();
    }
}

internal class Class2 {
    private Class3 _class3;
    
    internal Class2() {
        _class3 = new Class3(this);
    }
}

internal class Class3 {
    private Class2 _owner;
    
    internal Class3(Class2 owner) {
        _owner = owner;
    }
}
```

The `Class2` instance can reference its `Class3` instance via the `_class3` field, and the `Class3` instance can in turn reference its `Class2` owner via its `_owner` field;